# How to index the fields for performance?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table with around 1M data. I am executing this query which takes around 0.9 second to fetch records.

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.tag
FROM
    table as c
WHERE
    c.manufacturer = "some value"
    AND c.power = "some value"
    AND c.bolt = "some value"
    AND c.cylinder = "some value"
    AND c.drive = "some value"
    AND c.minSize <= "some value"
    AND c.speedMin = "some value"
    AND c.lengthMin  >= "some value"
    AND c.widthMin >= "some value"
    
GROUP BY c.manufacturer, c.class, c.version, c.minSize, c.bolt, c.innerBoltF, c.innerBoltR, c.body, c.drive, c.lengthMin, c.lengthMax, c.widthMin, c.widthMax, c.seats, c.speedMax, c.speedMin
```

I have indexed columns `manufacturer, power`

EXPLAIN gives me following result:

SIMPLE  c   index_merge manufacturer,power  manufacturer,power  77,4        57  Using intersect(manufacturer,power); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

In some cases, I may have range query for speed, length & width

E.G. `c.lengthMin  >= "some value" AND c.lengthMin  < "some value"`

I am not sure if 0.9s is good amount of speed.

But in my case I have to use UNION ALL. Lets say if above query is Query1 based on some condition, my final query look something like

```
Query1 UNION ALL Query2 UNION ALL Query3 ....
```

So for around 100 UNION ALL conditions, single execution is taking around 3-5 minutes which is slower. I have to use UNION ALL because I need to know which column is executing based on the condition.

Is it possible to add more indexes to perform the query execution faster ? What columns should I index for ?

Any help please.

Comment: you are not using any aggregate function. Why you have used group by clause ?

Comment: @AmitVerma do you mean use DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY ?

Comment: I am asking the reason for using group by  clause.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated question with Explain

Comment: @AmitVerma because i have to find id and tag based on that group by condition

Comment: You are misusing MySQL's notorious nonstandard implementation of GROUP BY. Please [read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).  And, 100 UNION ALL clauses means 100 sub queries, each of which could possibly need a different index to be satisfied efficiently.

Comment: @O. Jones yes as initially I need to query with ` select DISTINCT c.manufacturer, c.class, c.version, c.minSize, c.bolt, c.innerBoltF, c.innerBoltR, c.body, c.drive, c.lengthMin, c.lengthMax, c.widthMin, c.widthMax, c.seats, c.speedMax, c.speedMin`. But need other columns to return. Which I cannot solve so I used group by instead

Comment: When you ask a query optimization question, it's helpful to include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` for your table, so we don't have to guess at the columns, data types, indexes, or constraints you currently have.

Answer (score 3):

`INTERSECT` is a clue that you have two single-column indexes when a 'composite' index of two columns would be better.

```
    c.manufacturer = "some value"
AND c.power = "some value"
AND c.bolt = "some value"
AND c.cylinder = "some value"
AND c.drive = "some value"
AND c.speedMin = "some value"
```

Which 3 of those are likely to be the most selective?  Then make an index with those 3 columns.  That will *help* with the `WHERE` clause, thereby speeding up the query.  ("3" is arbitrary.)

I suspect you are allowing the user to specify an arbitrary subset of columns?  If so, then pick 6 pairs of columns that will be tested with "=" most often and make 2-column composite indexes.  ("6" and "2" are arbitrary.)

100 Selections in a Union may be quite inefficient.  Please elaborate on the goal of the query; the may be alternative solutions.  Show us an example (but stop after about 3 Union items.

When you have a "range" (eg, "<") test, put the relevant column *last* in the composite index.  And it is useless to include 2 range columns in the index.  That is, put any number of "=" columns, then at most 1 "range" column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Regarding the purpose of UNION ALL I have `select Id, 'c1' from tbl where condition1 union all select Id, 'c2' from tbl where conditions ...` from the same table. Are there any alternatives? I cannot run query 100 times which is more slower so I try to run once with union.

Comment: @SS - Those are different conditions?  And you want "either-or", not "both-and"?

Comment: Yes those are going to be different condition from an array.

Comment: You could use OR in the WHERE instead.

Comment: If I use OR then I won't know result based on which conditions. E.G. 'c1' if it's the result from condition 1 'c2' based on condition 2 ..

Comment: @SS - Something like this: `WHERE (power = 3 AND bolt = 17) OR (power = 11 AND drive = 4)`

Comment: To expand on the suggestion, you can also alternate the column in the select based on a composite condition, which will take precedence in order from left to right. `CASE WHEN (power,bolt) = (3,17) THEN c1 WHEN (power,drive) = (11,4) THEN c2 END` See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3kn545SUPZQKE4Wq7N9uLK/0) example.